# Get value from array in #define

Tags: arrays, c, c-preprocessor

I have an array defined in a preprocessor statement like that:

```
#define myArray {0,1,2,3}
```

When I try to get a value from that array without actually assigning it to a variable first, like so:

```
myArray[0];
```

the compiler complains and doesn't let me do that.

This is probably, because this also doesn't work:

```
{0,1,2,3}[0]
```

How can I get around this problem? I don't want to use multiple `#define` statements, and I also don't want to assign the array to a variable in memory first.

**Context**

I want to implement a patch for an opensource microcontroller project. RAM space is limited, and the whole data flow here is static.

I want to follow the code style in the config file, which uses a lot of array definitions like above.

On the other hand, I don't want to waste RAM space for a useless variable, when it could be done directly.

Comment: ... I think `inline` array won't be put into static memory in the compiled executable, which would solve your problem.

Comment: Although normally the executable size isn't a huge issue. What's your actual problem? Why don't you want to make it a real array?

Comment: Normally you have macros like these when you have large configurations of some big struct or array and want to swap them out by changing the initializer list. That means you'd access the actual variable with `[i]` rather than the macro.

Comment: I provided some more context in the OP.

Comment: I'm not sure if something like `((int[4]){1,2,3,4})` guarantees that the array is not in RAM. Also `const myArray[] = {0,1,2,3};` also might put your array not into RAM. It totally depends on your platform.

Comment: ... I meant `const int myArray[] = {0,1,2,3};`

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

In your case you can do

```
#define myArray ((int[4]){1,2,3,4})
```

I would not recommend using compound literals this way. It is unlikely that they are the best solution to your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` actually defines a MACRO that the compiler then expands at compilation time to create the executable code that you want.

So you could use:

```
#define MYARRAY {0,1,2,3}
int testArray[] = MYARRAY;
int element = testArray[0];
```

but `MYARRAY[0]` would make no sense to the compiler as there isn't enough information on how the macro should be expanded into executable code, thus it would flag an error.

A word of warning though in the above example the size of `testArray` isn't determined by the data assigned by the `MYARRAY` macro, although it will contain the values defined by it, and so the value returned by any `sizeof(...)` operation may be larger than you expect.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization – you might want to rewrite your last paragraph...

Comment: Not a criticism, but a pedantic point to ponder: Macros are replaced, not necessarily expanded. Sometimes macro replacement results in shorter code, not longer.

Comment: @Eric - thank you for you input, the wonders of the English language. In this case I was not stating that the code is increased in size, just that the macro statement is replaced by the defined code, which in all cases will be more than just the macro name otherwise you'd write the code long hand and not use a macro.